# Using xtable function on candisc::cancor output

Tags: r, knitr, sweave, xtable, rnw

I want to use `xtable` function on `candisc::cancor` output. But could not figure it out.

```
library(xtable)
library(candisc)
data(Rohwer, package="heplots")
X <- as.matrix(Rohwer[,6:10])  # the PA tests
Y <- as.matrix(Rohwer[,3:5])   # the aptitude/ability variables
(cc <- cancor(X, Y, set.names=c("PA", "Ability")))
Canonical correlation analysis of:
         5   PA  variables:  n, s, ns, na, ss 
  with   3   Ability  variables:  SAT, PPVT, Raven 

    CanR  CanRSQ   Eigen percent    cum                          scree
1 0.6703 0.44934 0.81599   77.30  77.30 ******************************
2 0.3837 0.14719 0.17260   16.35  93.65 ******                        
3 0.2506 0.06282 0.06704    6.35 100.00 **                            

Test of H0: The canonical correlations in the 
current row and all that follow are zero

     CanR  WilksL      F df1   df2  p.value
1 0.67033 0.44011 3.8961  15 168.8 0.000006
2 0.38366 0.79923 1.8379   8 124.0 0.076076
3 0.25065 0.93718 1.4078   3  63.0 0.248814
xtable(cc)

Error in UseMethod("xtable") : 
  no applicable method for 'xtable' applied to an object of class "cancor"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at `methods(xtable)` there is no method for `cancor` objects but there is `xtable.data.frame` which we could hopefully use, as the output of `cancor` look like `data.frames`.

However, these values are not returned by `cancor` - look at `str(cc)`. They are calculated in the `print` method. Look at `candisc:::print.cancor`.

So create a quick extraction function to generate the `cancor` output as `data.frames`

```
outfun <- function(X) { 
              CanR = X$cancor  
              CanRSQ = CanR^2  
              Eigen = CanRSQ/(1 - CanRSQ)
              percent = 100 * Eigen/sum(Eigen)
              cum = cumsum(percent)
              list(tab1 = data.frame(CanR, CanRSQ, Eigen, percent, cum) ,
                   tab2 = as.data.frame(candisc:::Wilks.cancor(X)))
        }
```

Run helper function

```
(out <- outfun(cc))

# or run it like
out <- outfun(cancor(X, Y, set.names=c("PA", "Ability")))
```

Can then use `xtable.data.frame` to generate the `xtable` output

```
xtable:::xtable.data.frame(out[[1]])

# % latex table generated in R 3.1.1 by xtable 1.7-3 package
# % Wed Sep 17 18:32:07 2014
# \begin{table}[ht]
# \centering
# \begin{tabular}{rrrrrr}
#   \hline
#  & CanR & CanRSQ & Eigen & percent & cum \\ 
#   \hline
# 1 & 0.67 & 0.45 & 0.82 & 77.30 & 77.30 \\ 
#   2 & 0.38 & 0.15 & 0.17 & 16.35 & 93.65 \\ 
#   3 & 0.25 & 0.06 & 0.07 & 6.35 & 100.00 \\ 
#    \hline
# \end{tabular}
# \end{table}

xtable:::xtable.data.frame(out[[2]])
```

You can tweak the helper function to also extract headers and such which can then be passed to `xtable.data.frame` as arguments.

A quick answer that may get you started

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and providing very useful answer. Much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Need to make few changes in `as.data.frame(candisc:::Wilks.cancor(cc))` because `cc` is not defined.

Comment: cheers, again forgetting to clear my workspace before posting ;)